# Dom replace entire node

Tags: php, dom

Right now, i have this:

```
$text = $row->text;
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($text);
$tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $eg = $tag->getAttribute('data-easygal');
    $src = $tag->getAttribute('src');
    $values = explode("_",$eg);
    $display = $this->prepareAlbum($values[0],$values[1],$src);
}
$row->text = $text;
```

is there a way to replace the whole node $tag, with what's in the $display string? I cant seem to find out how to str_replace the node for example.
Used to have preg_replace but that doesnt work properly on the clients server even though it works at home (and some instant anger from the php community with preg and html)

Tried searching the board, but no luck in finding what i need :S

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
foreach($tags as &$tag) {
    ...
    $tag = new DomNode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$tag-> parentNode ->replaceChild($newNode, $tag);
```

should replace the `$tag` node with `$newNode` - A DOM node that you create in the usual way.

Comment: thing is, i need to put a string, in its place, not a new dom.

Comment: Use `createTextNode(text)`